# Creating JS functions to use anywhere? Problems with scope and functions being "undefined"

Tags: javascript, scope, undefined

So I'm still quite new to JS, and one of my biggest frustrations is SCOPE.
I have read a lot of guides, and I know when we can and when we can't use certain variables, but I never understand where my mistakes are.
I want to create a bunch of JS functions I can use anywhere in my document, however, I often get the bug that says function is not defined...

**My case:**

I add an external script file in the `<head>`. Inside the script.js I have a function called: launch_ajax.

```
launch_ajax = function(){
    console.log("fire");
};
window.launch_ajax() = launch_ajax();
```

Then at the bottom of my body I have `launch_ajax();` but is gives me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: launch_ajax is not defined

Please don't scold me for being stupid... =(

Comment: `window.launch_ajax() =` doesn't look right

Comment: Is it window.launch_ajax = launchajax(); ?

Comment: @elclanrs is right. Just remove this ```window.launch_ajax() = launch_ajax();``` and define your function in the global scope ```function launch_ajax(){}```. You need to import function to the ```window``` object only if it's defined in another scope.

Comment: No need to assign it to window, it'll automatically be a window function if you do function launch_ajax(){} as Alexander Popov stated, 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp1

Comment: What about a `;` at the end?  If I write `launch_ajax = function(){}` do I need to add a `;` ?

Comment: semicolon is not necessary since they serve to separate statements and a function declaration is not a statement..

Comment: So is it better to write `function launch_ajax(){}` or `launch_ajax = function(){}` ?

Comment: Hey guys I added my exact use case that's giving me the problem. I tried everything.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/76g4fco1/

I added the declaration inline, but the result is the same as an external js-file, is this somewhat like your solution? Apart from me using an alert instead of console.log :)

Comment: I'm not sure why but mine is still bugging...

Comment: Here's the link: http://jtc.ae/?page=s_page&p_num=1&item_num=20

Comment: You have an error at row 275 in searchgrid.js and since launch_ajax is declared after that, it will not be found. My suggestion for this question is to put launch_ajax before the error at row 275 just to see that there is nothing wrong with launch_ajax and then fix the error :)

Comment: I put launch_ajax at the very beginning now and it still bugs. =S
I'm not sure why they suddenly say `Unexpected token [` because it has always worked in the past...

Comment: Well I found out the problem was completely different: I had the line `var post_meta['exw_from_usd'] = 'something';` while it already existed, so to update the value apparently I had to delete the `var`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
launch_ajax = function(){
    console.log("fire");
};
```

That will create a global variable with the name *launch_ajax* and assign it the function on the right hand side.

```
window.launch_ajax() = launch_ajax();
```

That is a function call, immediately followed by an assignment and will write "fire" to the console then throw an error about an invalid assignment. Script execution should stop there.

If what you actually have is:

```
window.launch_ajax = launch_ajax();
```

then you are assigning the result of calling *launch_ajax* to *window.launch_ajax*. Since the function has no return statement, it returns *undefined* so the value of *window.launch_ajax* is now undefined. If you try to call it later, you'll get an error message about *launch_ajax* not being a function.

Comment: So the very top way you wrote it is the best way? And that's with a `;` at the end?

Comment: If using a function expression, I'd use the *var* keyword to declare the variable. But I'd use a function declaration instead.

Comment: what's a function expression? (sorry)